# WP8 open settings page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, settings

I would open Settings Application from my app, but i didn't find nothing to open it. I found how to open an option of settings as for example cellular, wifi, location etc with this snipptes:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(uri-options));
```

but i want open Settings page (not an option of settings). I haven't found any URI for general settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do. To navigate to built in apps you have this list of Uri's

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to launch that page directly but what you can do is to launch each and every one of them individually using the `LaunchUriAsync()` method.

Check [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-Launch-settings-6d68c5ba) sample from msdn.

Hope it helps!